# Can't link js file to html file in flask template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, flask

In my project there is folder named `mine` with 2 subfolders (static folder & templates folder) and 1 app.py file init.

I have put my jQuery script file inside the static folder and shop.html file is in the templates folder. I want to link that html file to that js file.

I put this inside the html file:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='/static/hide.js') }}"></script>
```

But it does not work? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have a duplicate `'static'` in there:

```
url_for('static', filename='hide.js')
```

The first `'static'` will automatically populate with the URL which points to the static folder, therefore putting `'static'` in the `filename` field is redundant.

```
url_for('static', filename='static/hide.js')
# '/static/static/hide.js'

url_for('static', filename='hide.js')
# '/static/hide.js'
```

Comment: Yes I know that but `<script type=text/javascript src="{{url_for('static', filename='hide.js') }}"></script>` didn't work for me that I changed the path.

Comment: Oh yeah I found the problem, just was a little mistake. But thank you for explaining.